# Text To Speech configuration for actions-on-google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, ssml

I have an application developed using Dialogflow and actions-on-google framework.

When I provide a response which has numbers in it the text to speech engine pronounces 0 (Zero) as "O" (Oh)

Is there any way where I can configure not to speak 0 (Zero) as "O" (Oh) and should always speak "ZERO"

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can look the documentation for [SSML](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) to provide more specific nuances in the text-to-speech response.

If you want to say specific characters, you should be able to use an SSML `say-as` tag:

```xml
<speak>
  <say-as interpret-as="characters">1234567890</say-as>
</speak>
```

Comment: thanks Nick. Your link is helpful but even though we took your suggestion it still speaks 0 (Zero) as O (Oh). Can you please advise?

Comment: At that point it could be a speech synthesis problem. I guess you could go through your text and replace "0" with "zero" to get synthesis working as expected.

Comment: That would probably fix but will display text as zero instead of 0!

Answer (score 0):

Using sub alias of speak element fixed my issue

```
<speak>This is test<sub alias="one one zero seven">1107</sub> </speak>
```